# Forms for a Content Type

Tags: 2013, content-type

Well, I'm kind of new on this of content types but I was wondering if it's possible to associate a form to a content type? this is the scenario:

I have to create some document libraries with a certain content type but I want for all that document libraries a custom New Form but I want to keep having the advantages of the Content Types (If I modify the content type I want all libraries update the structure too).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can create content types at site collection level and add it to respective document libraries. Now if you change the content type in Site Collection level, the changes will get reflected automatically in library level (provided you haven't updated the content type at list level)

Content Type has following properties

1. EditFormUrl
2. NewFormUrl
3. DisplayFormUrl

As the name suggested, if you want to have a custom new form, then you should update the `NewFormUrl` property. You can do this based on how you created the content type.

Typically we do this using Visual Studio, in that case you can set the via `Elements.XML` file or via `Feature Receiver` etc.

Comment: Is there a way to do it in SPD?

Comment: Yes. You can open up the Content Type and use the summary page for the content type

Comment: Ok, when i go there the content type properties are listed but in the forms box I have per form an input text ("<Click to enter text>" ). Should i put there the url to the form? where does the form should be? Do i have restrictions here? Do you have an example of this?

Comment: You can put the URL of the custom page you created.

Comment: Do you have a link of an example for this please?

Comment: Can i place my custom new form in any place of the site collection?